# How to mock an api for a React stateless functional component?

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs, fetch

I am trying to test a Stateless Functional React component that makes a Fetch call during the useEffect lifecycle hook.  I would like to make a mock api file which will intercept this call when running Jest unit tests, but I have had no luck in trying to make this happen.

My Component: App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Form from './Form';
import Image from './Image';
import unsplash from '../services/unsplash';

function App() {
  const [deStat, setDeStat] = useState({
    term: '',
    images: [],
    status: 'initial'
  });

  const fetchImages = async term => {
    setDeStat({
      status: 'searching',
      term: term,
      images: []
    });

    try {
      const images = await unsplash(term);
      setDeStat({
        status: 'done',
        images
      });
    } catch (error) {
      setDeStat({
        status: 'error'
      });
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchImages('Mountains');
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form fetchImages={fetchImages} />

      {deStat.status === 'searching' && <h3>Searching for {deStat.term}</h3>}
      {deStat.status === 'done' && deStat.images.length === 0 && (
        <h3>
          Sorry sucker, no results{' '}
          <span role="img" aria-label="sad">
            
          </span>
        </h3>
      )}
      {deStat.status === 'error' && <h3>Oops... error!</h3>}

      <div className="images-container">
        <h5>Images okay!</h5>
        {deStat.images.map(image => (
          <Image image={image} key={image.id} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My Mock Service (`services/__mocks__/unsplash.js`):

```
const fakeData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    categories: [{ title: "Nice image" }],
    user: {
      name: "Mr. Photographer"
    },
    links: {
      html: "https://www.leighhalliday.com"
    },
    urls: {
      small: "https://www.image.com/nice.jpg"
    },
    likes: 10
  }
];

export default async term => {
  return await new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(fakeData);
  });
};
```

My test (not working as the mock is not being called):

```
import App from './App';

jest.mock('../services/unsplash');

it('fetches images from unsplash and renders them on mount', done => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<App />);

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('inside timeout App2!');
    wrapper.update();

    expect(wrapper.find('Image').length).toEqual(1);

    done();
  });
});
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?  I want to use a custom function for the fetch call instead of the real one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `act()` to `flush async events.`

https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act

Also make your test `async` like so it

```
("should blah", async () => {}
```

Also in your mock, returning a promise inside `async` `await`
is redundant. Use one or the other.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about how to use `act()` with a stateless functional component?  The examples in the link you provided are for class-based components, and they definitely function differently.  Perhaps you could alter my existing code to show how to use `act()` properly?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JeremyMoritz The `act` replaces `setTimeout` in that it will flush any side effects that are time based (asynchronous).  No need to change your component. No need to call wrapper.update() Also I noticed your are calling unsplash from services. As long as services is using unsplash lib your mock should be fine

Comment: @JeremyMoritz Mocks in the __mocks__ folder automatically mock your dependencies. Structure should be __mocks__/services/unsplash
You need to redo the structure.